# Test COM port LED custmer display using windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, serial-port

I buy customer display that customer display has  PL-2303HXD chip. The customer display connect to COM1 to my PC.I can send any number using test software come with that customer display. but I can't display any value using cmd in windows.
In the [manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6aE04zeZiMtcU12ZHh5WmlfX1U/edit?usp=sharing)  ask to try

```
C: \> MODE COM1 2400, N, 8,1 
C: \> TYPE CON> COM1
```

in cmd but that not work for me. please tell how can i test customer display using cmd in windows.

**Instructions for application:**

1. Use the standard RS232 serial port (baud rate= 2400, parity =none, data bits = 8, stop 
   bit = 1).
2. Use international ESC / POS Common set of commands, do not need to install any drivers. Both under DOS or WINDOWS platform, just follow the format of the commandset to send data to the serial port to display the content, without handshake.

Comment: What are you [typing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=international+ESC+%2F+POS+Common+set+of+commands&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=international+esc+%2F+pos+common+set+of+commands&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=e83694870bb14df998b42fcaff064b30) after you redirect the Console to your ComPort?

Comment: just type (123)numbers after that press Enter key